# Code performance on double for loop compare to linq/lambda

Tags: c#, performance, linq, for-loop, lambda

I like the look of linq/lambda statement and wonder about the performance of this

```
var temp = list1.ForEach(x => list2.ForEach(y => Tuple.Create(y[1]+" "+y[2]+" "+x[0]+" "+x[1]) );
```

compared to this:

```
foreach(var x in list1)
  foreach(var y in list2)
    var temp = Tuple.Create(y[1]+" "+y[2]+" "+x[0]+" "+x[1]);
```

Still not familiar with how people describe performance in terms of O(nlogn) but from constant interaction with this type of chat I understand the double loop gives usually O(n^2)

Comment: do the two different code sets preform the same?

Comment: Both have two nested for loops. Both are the same (In performance)

Comment: There is no LINQ anywhere in this code.

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion any of your approaches could be `O(n log n)`? Or is this just an example?

Comment: @Servy ok. I am still unfamiliar with terminology for these. Like what is the first code called? Also i know there is what query vs. method terms, as well as statement vs. expression.

Comment: @HimBromBeere no I was stating I don't understand the use of the performance term and what it actually equates to

Comment: @Edward The first is just using an instance method on `List`.  The second is using a `foreach` statement, which is a part of the language.  LINQ is a collection of objects/methods in a namespace, unrelated to either of these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both statements are equal on their complexity, namely `O(n^2)`. Internally the `ForEach`-statement will create a simply loop doing what is determined by the lambda-statement. So the total number of calls to the inner code is the same making both approaches similar in their complexity.

Anyway to get meaningful results on your actual **time-performance** you should use some profiling-tools, e.g. [Resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Alternatively simply add some [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) statements into your code to measure how long things need to proceed.

Comment: damn, you beat me to this while i was writing it >.<

Comment: Me? where is that option?

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler turns these into machine readable code, both are doing the same function. This specific case is just a nested loop either way. Both should be O(n^2) i believe and its a matter of what you think looks better in this case. because you have list1.foreach, then inside list2.foreach its the same as writing

```
foreach()
{
    foreach()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer anyway.